# QGIS field calculator get value of spefici cell

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

How can I access the values of specific cells in my attribute table in QGIS in the Fieldcalculator?

For a calculation I need two values of the column "height" with a certain ID and not always the complete column "height".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have this table:

| id | value_shp001 | value_shp002 | value_shp003 | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 10 | 254 | QGIS LTR |
| 2 | 34 | 25 | 32 | QGIS RC |
| 3 | 100 | 150 | 541 | QGIS dev |

to access the cell `value_shp002`, `id = 2`, just use the expression

```
array_agg ("value_shp002")[1] → 25
```

Note: the array index starts from 0, i.e. the first row would be 0, the second 1, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Use the `get_feature()` function to pick out a specific feature from a layer, and then use the `attributes()` function to specify an attribute to pull from that feature.

So to get the "height" from feature with "id" number 3 from "your_layer" you would use:
`attributes(get_feature('your_layer', 'id', 3))['height']`

Comment: I always get the error: "syntax error,unexpected Unknown_CHARACTER, expecting $end"

Comment: Build the expression slowly. Does `get_feature('your_layer', 'id', 3)` give you a preview in the field calculator of something like <feature: x> ? If so then try `attributes(get_feature('your_layer', 'id', 3))`  and it should preview a list of attributes. Try to find where the expression is breaking down.